# Replace part of a string in column

Tags: python, pandas, string

I want to delete part of a string in a pandas dataframe in Python. The column contain invoice line with a period specified. See below. I want to delete this part the part between the [*].
Image dataset (https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdCnV.png)

I have tried method str replace. `df['Description_GLEntry'].str.replace('[Jan 01, 2022 - Jan 31, 2022]', '')`. This removes the text, but leaves me with [-] and it does not specifically delete [*]. My plan was to make it work with a loop in a def function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the following regex replacement:

```py
df["Description_GLEntry"] = df["Description_GLEntry"].str.replace(r'\s*\[\w{3} \d{2}, \d{4} - \w{3} \d{2}, \d{4}\]$', '', regex=True)
```

Here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oqFtFo/1) showing that the replacement logic is working against your test data.

Comment: That work. I get a message in Jypeter: C:\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_12828\2186437461.py:1: FutureWarning: The default value of regex will change from True to False in a future version.
  df["Description_GLEntry"] = df["Description_GLEntry"].str.replace(r'\s*\[\w{3} \d{2}, \d{4} - \w{3} \d{2}, \d{4}\]$', ''). It that OK?

Comment: Add `Regex=True` as the 3rd parameter to `str.replace` to make the warning go away.